# No safe area insets value available. Make sure you are rendering `<SafeAreaProvider>` at the top of your app. - how can i ressolve this error?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

```js
export default class CalorieScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { text: "" };
  }
  render() {
    const { calories } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header
          backgroundColor={"#9c8210"}
          centerComponent={{
            text: "Monkey Chunky",
            style: { padding: 100, color: "#fff", fontSize: 20 },
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I created a login screen that goes into my calorie screen when i click the buttun it takes me to the screen but this error appears

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are rendering `<SafeAreaProvider>` at the top of your app. Something like this.

```js
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

...
  return <SafeAreaProvider>...</SafeAreaProvider>;
...
```

Answer (score 4):

**wrapp all the component in SafeAreaProvide in app.js**

```
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
```

...
return ...;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74663537/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using react-native-elements make sure you install version 2.2.1

Comment: already installed all versions

Comment: But is react-native-elements 2.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of incompatible versions of recently released expo-router with other components:

```bash
npx npm-check-updates -u
npm start --clean-cache
```